# python keyword for an approximation of a real number like 0.0

Tags: python-3.x

So is it global or float?

The example 0.0 is a float in python.

Though float is not a keyword so I would think that it would be global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm uncertain about var types, which is a lot since I am new to python, I go into shell_plus and check stuff out like this:

In [1]: x = 0.0

In [2]: print type(x)

For me this produces: type 'float'